# Get all polylines from a shapefile (containing polylines)

Tags: arcpy, features, line

I have a `*.shp` file which contains only polyline features. How can I iterate over all the point features. Given [ESRI Polyline example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000n2000000) only uses already defined points to make polylines. But I want to iterate over all the polylines found on a shapefile.

How can I do this using ArcPy?

Answer (score 3):

This is directly from the ESRI Help File:  [Accessing Data using Cursors](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Accessing_data_using_cursors/002z0000001q000000/)

> This example shows a simple cursor operation. It prints out name and value of each string field for each row in a feature class.

```
import arcpy

fc = "D:/st_johns/roads.shp"

# Create a search cursor 
#
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc) 

# Create a list of string fields
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "", "String")

for row in rows:
    for field in fields:
        if field.type != "Geometry":
            print "%s: Value = %s" % (field.name, row.getValue(field.name))
```

When you reach the line:

```
for row in rows:
```

You have a cursor that will iterate through the rows that represent the features in the shapefile.  I encourage you to search through the ESRI Help files for Accessing Geographic Data with Python.  [Describing Data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Describing_data/002z00000018000000/) is the first section.

This example allows you to directly access the geometry of each feature and returns the length.

```
import arcpy

fc = "D:/st_johns/roads.shp"

# Create a search cursor 
#
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc) 

length = 0

shapeName = arcpy.Describe(fc).shapeFieldName

for row in rows:
  feat = row.getValue(shapeName)
  length += feat.length

# Print the total length of all roads
#
print length
```

The previous example was from the help file on [Working with geometry in python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Working_with_geometry_in_Python/002z0000001s000000/)

Answer (score 0):

.

beside @Get Spatial solution, you should check out Iterate Feature Selection (ModelBuilder) [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000000s000000.htm).

> Summary
>
> Iterates over features in a feature class.

[image: iterate]

i hope it helps you...